# UICollectionView линия между ячейками

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

Всем привет! У меня есть `UICollectionView`, в котором мне надо нарисовать линии между ячейками (границы). Я создал метод

```
- (void) drawSeparatorWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    CALayer *separator = [CALayer layer];
    separator.frame = frame;
    separator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
    [self.layer addSublayer:separator];
}
```

и вызываю его так

```
if (indexPath.row != 0) {
    [cell drawSeparatorWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0.5, cell.frame.size.height)];
} else {
    NSLog(@"\nIndexPath.row == 0\n");
}
```

Блок If добавлен для того, чтобы не рисовать линию на первой ячейке, т.к. мне не нужны линии по бокам крайних ячеек. Мой метод рисует линию слева от ячейки, поэтому не рисую только на первой, т.е. когда indexPath.row равен 0.

Проблема заключается в следующем. При запуске программы UICollectionView формируется как надо и линия на первой ячейке не рисуется, НО стоит мне промотать вправо от первой ячейки и обратно промотать к ней как эта самая полосочка рисуется! и в консоль выводится NSLog - сообщение `nIndexPath.row == 0`. В голову не приходит почему метод вызывается. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне быть?

Answer (score 3):

Ячейки коллекции в ios перезаполняются при прокрутке, то есть в той же самой ячейке у вас потом рисуется линия, а при возвращении назад она никак не затирается. Можете всегда рисовать линию, и скрывать примерно так:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
   [cell.separator setHidden:YES];
 } else {
   [cell.separator setHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в класс ячейки метод [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/prepareForReuse), в этом методе удаляйте layer-разделитель.